# Rails 4: how to make exceptions to wildcard routes so I an access mail previews?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, routes, actionmailer

In `routes.rb` I have the following:

```
get '*category/*location' => 'landing#show'
get '*category' => 'landing#show'
```

This is keeping me from being able to view mail previews at `/rails/previews` because I get redirected just as if I had typed `/painting` or `/painting/chicago`.

Using the Rails routing guides, I tried to make constraints like this:

```
  get '*category/*location' => 'landing#show', constraints: { category: /(?!rails)/, location: /(?!mailers)/ }
  get '*category' => 'landing#show', constraints: { category: /(?!rails\/mailers)/ }
```

...however, this seems to either be blocking everything *except* `/rails/mailers` (I can now open the mail previews but all of the previous dynamic behavior is broken) or it's just made the two lines null - not sure which. All I can tell is that I can now access the mail previews but the previously dynamic behavior is broken.

The other idea I had was simply to skip over the wildcard lines if I'm not in development like so:

```
  unless Rails.env.development?
    get '*category/*location' => 'landing#show'
    get '*category' => 'landing#show'
  end
```

However, this seems a bit ham-fisted. It prevents me from viewing the wildcard behavior in development, and I'm just wondering if there's a better way using constraints. Can someone help me figure out what I need to do to get those wildcards to work *unless* the url ends in `/rails/server`.

Comment: Not seeing why you can't just put your `get '/rails/previews'` route higher in the `routes.rb` file than your wildcard routes.

Comment: that results in `uninitialized constant RailsController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the solution in @gregates' comment (set `get '/rails/previews'` above the wildcards) but got the error `uninitialized constant RailsController`. However, the suggestion made me think to look at how the request is being processed when it works correctly, so I removed the wildcards, just accessed the mailers normally, and saw this:

```
Processing by Rails::MailersController#index as HTML
```

So I added the following to the top of my routes file and now everything works correctly:

```
# routes.rb
...
get '/rails/mailers' => 'rails/mailers#index'
...
```

Comment: I used `get 'rails/mailers', to: 'rails/mailers#index'` which worked for me, I had to remove the leading `/`.